# Exception while deserializing DataTable with custom DataType columns using BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization, datatable, binaryformatter

I'm writing a client-server application. I want to send `DataTable table` where most of columns are of type Pair. I have that `public class Pair` inside `public class Struct` on both Server and Client.

```
[Serializable]
public class Struct
{
    public class Pair
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public int b { get; set; }
            ...
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.a.ToString() + " " + this.b.ToString();
        }
    }
        ...
}
```

I send it from server:

```
(new BinaryFormatter()).Serialize(nStream, table);
```

Accept on client:

```
DataTable table = (DataTable)(new BinaryFormatter()).Deserialize(nStream);
```

And here I get a

> TargetInvocationException "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" with
>   InnerException: ArgumentException "Column requires a valid DataType".

How to send this table over network and deserialize it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the inner class as `[Serializable]` also:

```
[Serializable]
public class Struct
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Pair
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public int b { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A nested class is not a subclass, it's an [independent type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx) that happens to have access to the protected and private members of its containing type.

Also, are you actually linking the *same [assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* that contains your `Struct` in both the client and server, or did you just copy the code?  [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) actually records the assembly name and version of the types being serialized, and if, upon deserialization, that specific assembly is not found, deserialization will fail.  See [How to serialize/deserialize an object loaded from another assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183787/how-to-serialize-deserialize-an-object-loaded-from-another-assembly)