# C# Serialize Exception

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

this is my Serialize and Deserialize code

```
  public byte[] DTSerialize(object dt)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, dt);
        return stream.GetBuffer();
    }


    public object DTDeserialize(byte[] buffer)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        return formatter.Deserialize(stream) as object;
    }
```

and this call method code

```
        List<Series> ser = new List<Series>();
        foreach (Series item in chartControl1.Series)
        {
            ser.Add(item);
        }


byte[] btt = DTSerialize(ser);
```

but when i call code this exception throwing

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Type 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.Series' in
>   Assembly 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.v14.1, Version=14.1.4.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' is not marked as
>   serializable.

Comment: can you use json as your serialization format?

Comment: What is ser?? Is it 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.Series object??

Comment: no this is win application

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Not marked as Serializable means that the class you are trying to serialize (list of series) doesn't have a [Serializable] on it. You can easily search on google on how to serialize a list. edit: example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005900/how-to-serialize-listt

Comment: Hold on - the error clearly says " is not marked as serializable", so you won't be able to serialize it. EDIT - post one second after SpaceSteak (ie im not commenting on SpaceSteak's comment; I agree with him)

Comment: One more question - you are trying to serialize a UI component; but isn't it better to serialize whichever data you used to render the component (i.e. im assuming you did some binding of data to the control)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to serialize object which is not market with `[Serializable]` attribute, i.e. it won't work.

Comment: One more question to the OP (already posted above): you are trying to serialize a UI component; but isn't it better to serialize whichever data you used to render the component (i.e. im assuming you did some binding of data to the control)

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the object from any assembly. Check the below link. It may help you.

[How to serialize/deserialize an object loaded from another assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183787/how-to-serialize-deserialize-an-object-loaded-from-another-assembly)